# How to link data in 2 different class objects without storing the data twice

Tags: java, class

This is a question more about technique. I have an Environment class, that is a 2D array of location blocks.

```
Class Environment{
EnvBlock[][] envBlockGrid; 
...}
```

In these blocks there can be any number of objects.

```
class EnvBlock {
public ArrayList<EnvObj> envObjs;
```

One of these objects could be a person, say Fred.

```
class Person extends EnvObj{
//does not contain info on location in environment
```

In main:

```
Person fred = new Person;
Environment env = new Environment;
env.envBlockGrid[3][5].envObjs.add(fred);
```

The environment object will store a reference to Fred object in the 2D array. But I also want the Fred object to have the location information, for example he might want to look at the block in front of him.

To do this at the moment I'm searching through the environment 2D array to find the location of Fred then looking at the block in front of him, this seems a bit inefficient.

But if I save the 2D coordinate location of Fred in the Fred object then that's duplicating this location information, which doesn't seem right either and could lead to programming errors, for example the coordinates stored in Fred might be updated when Fred moves but the other set in the environment object aren't.

Only storing the location in the person object isn't ideal either because then if I want to see what is in front of Fred I'd have to search through all the objects that exist to see if any are at those coordinates.

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense, I'm relatively new to this and I've not posted on these forums before.
Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Could you provide some code snippets to show the classes, the data you wish to "link" and how you want to use or access that data?

Comment: It’s not always possible to store information only once and also support efficient lookup.  This is one of the main reasons for encapsulation: then you have to get the synchronization between the representations right only once.

Comment: Add previous object in constructor maybe? `New fred = new Person( env.envBlockGrid[3][4] )`

Comment: And if he moves, provide method to change prev object.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's really useful.